# Jquery,how to append the a div in another div and replace the older html from that div?

Tags: jquery

how to append the a div in another div and replace the older html from that div?
Like I have a div which I want to be filled with new entry every time.

Comment: Show us your code and what you have tried!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use html() of jquery like this `$('yourdivid').html('thenewhtml')`. It will replace the old html with new one.

Comment: let me try and i will let you know.

Comment: ok. let me know if you have issue.

Answer (score 0):

How about removing the previous children and adding the new content or directly replace the div content by calling .html() function of jquery?

```
$(parentselector).html('new html content');
```

or

```
$(parentselector).empty()
$(parentselector).append('html content' or element)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shree/z7L1yooo/)

Html

```
<div id="1">
  test1
</div>
<input type='button' id='test' value='Test' />
```

Jquery

```
var newDiv = '<div id="2">test2</div>';
$("#test").on("click", function() {
  $("#1").html('');
  $("#1").append(newDiv);
});
```